# Sublime Text 3: Color coding removed for javascript

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I was installing some packages of Sublime Text 3 and after installing a package called *"Better JavaScript"* an error appeared (don't remember exactly) but my code coloring for JavaScript files was gone and it shows a blank; white text right now. I've removed the package and reinstalled the program but the problem persists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: make sure it's saved as a .js file, and that javascript syntax is active (ctrl+shift+p -> set-syntax -> javascript)

Comment: In the bottom right corner of the editor, there is a menu you can slide up, check that it is set to javascript and not text.

Comment: See if inside Packages folder of installed directory for sublime, Javascript folder exists or not...

Comment: it didn't exist in the "Packages" folder.

Comment: @Alex yeah! already selected jQuery(Javascript) there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure it's saved as a .js file, and that javascript syntax is active (ctrl+shift+p -> set-syntax -> javascript)